# How much memory space does an ArangoDB index need?

Tags: arangodb

I'd like to calculate our server requirements for ArangoDB.

I know that ArangoDB stores the indexes in RAM, but how much space do indexes use?

Comment: That depends on the type of index. Just the Hash-Index for the primary? The edges index for graphs? Or also Geo or Fulltext?

Comment: the output of the `figures` method of a collection should also show the memory requirements of the indexes of the collection. For example, call HTTP PUT `/_api/collection/<collection-name>/figures` for the collection of choice and there should be an `indexes` return attribute with a `size` sub-attribute, showing the memory size of indexes. This should work in ArangoDB 2.2 and up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depend on the kind of index you use.

You can use "figures" to see how many memory is needed:

```
arangosh [_system]> db.test.ensureSkiplist("attribute1")
arangosh [_system]> db.test.ensureFulltextIndex("attribute2");
arangosh [_system]> db._query("FOR i IN 1 .. 1000 INSERT { 'attribute1': i, 'attribute2': 'Text' } INTO test");
arangosh [_system]> db.test.figures()
...
  "indexes" : { 
    "count" : 3, 
    "size" : 77376 
  },
```

Is the total amount needed for all indexes. There is always the primary index.

For a hash index the memory consumption is roughly:

```
4 * n * sizeof(void*)
```

where n is the number of documents.